# how many distinct values does it have?

Tags: combinatorics

I solved this problem by manually adding parentheses and counting them, and got correct answer of 32. Is there a simple to find the answer? Thanks.

> The value of the expression $1÷2÷3÷5÷7÷11÷13$ can be altered by including parentheses. If we are allowed to place as many parentheses as we want, how many distinct values can be obtained for this expression?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansProblem.html

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: The Catalan numbers count the number of fully parenthesized _expressions_ here, but do not take into account that some of these expressions have the same value -- for example, $$(1\div( 2\div3))\div 5 = \frac{3}{10} = 1\div (2\div(3\div 5)$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Mystery solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In general, inserting parentheses in
 $$ a_1 \div a_2 \div a_3 \div \cdots \div a_n $$
can produce every number of the form
$$ a_1^{\strut}a_2^{-1}a_3^{s_3} a_4^{s_4} \cdots a_n^{s_n}$$
(and only those), where each $s_i$ is either $1$ or $-1$. Note that the exponents of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are fixed.

If $a_3$ through $a_n$ are coprime (as is the case here), this gives $2^{n-2}$ different possible values.

**Proof** by induction on $n$. The base case is $n=2$ where there is only a single possibility.

For $n>2$, first parenthesize $a_1\div\cdots\div a_{n-1}$ in order to get the desired exponents for $a_1$ through $a_{n-1}$.

Then, if the desired $s_n$ is opposite to $s_{n-1}$ then just replace $a_{n-1}$ by $(a_{n-1}\div a_n)$.

Otherwise the desired exponents $s_n$ and $s_{n-1}$ are equal. Let $E$ be the fully parenthesized expression such that $(E\div a_{n-1})$ is a subexpression of what we got from the induction hypothesis (that is, $E$ is the left operand to the division whose immediate right operand is $a_{n-1}$, and such a division always exists because $n-1\ge 2$), and replace this entire subexpression with $((E \div a_{n-1})\div a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

adding parenthesis changes the answer at all points but the end point due to the orders of operation. we have 6 divisions and one doesn't count so 5. each parentheses can either be included or not included so 2 options. in the end we have $2^5=32$

Comment: There are 132 (not 32) different binary trees with 7 leaves, and each of them can be produced by some parenthesization of original string. The argument that "each parentheses can either be included or not included" is certainly too much of a simplification here.

Comment: @henning makholm I counted division signs and subtracted 1. the binary is from 5 not 7 and is 32. and my equation gives the same answer as yours in all cases. plus mine was explained more simply. how is it "over simplified" when it always yields same answer

Comment: x @shai: Getting the right answer for the wrong reason is still wrong. And this _is_ a wrong reason -- there are not 5 places where parenthesis pairs can be placed or not placed independently of each other here.